# Lightroom have been importing and changing some settings of my pictures

Tags: lightroom

master from lightroom.

Every single time when I import my pictures to lightroom some of the settings are not in the Zero position.

Like this:

[image]

If I double click in the setting to reset it, like the normal behaviour, nothing happens as well.

I can't remember to change something in the lightroom to have this behaviour.

Can someone help me with it?

**Update**
Reset Lightroom didn't fix it. Could be something in the raw files?

Comment: Are you using a Preset? These might be the default if ALL the values are always the same. If not, do you have XMP files near your images. Another software might have written them and Lightroom is using these during import.

Comment: I don't think so, I just imported Lightroom classic. and all the pictures have the same values. I'm thinking if it could be something from my Camera, But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Very strange. I have never seen this even though I have been used Lightroom for over 10 years and have imported images from most digital camera models since 2006 since I review cameras. The only time I know that images can be imported like this is when an Import Preset is defined.

Comment: Are you importing a DNG file from a smartphone?

Comment: @AbdulNQuraishi, no, My images came from my Nikon D780

Answer (score 3):

To get back to the default, check the lightroom preset preference settings and make sure they look like this with Adobe Default set as master and nothing else active.

[image]